# Never ending spinning dots when logging into Windows with Azure AD account

Tags: azure-active-directory

I use an answer file to install Windows 10 20H2.  Then I join the computer to Azure AD. Then when I try to login into Windows with an Azure AD account, I see spinning dots instead of what should be pin creation. I have let the spinning go on for 12+ hours with no change. The problem does not exist when the same OS is installed without using the answer file.  I have tried commenting out sections of the Autounattend.xml file to try to isolate the problematic setting but it seems like the only way it login works is without an answer file at all.

Here is the answer file I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="windowsPE">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE"
                   processorArchitecture="amd64"
                   publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
                   language="neutral"
                   versionScope="nonSxS"
                   xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SetupUILanguage>
                <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            </SetupUILanguage>
            <InputLocale>0409:00000409</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>en-US</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            <UILanguageFallback>en-US</UILanguageFallback>
            <UserLocale>en-US</UserLocale>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup"
                   processorArchitecture="amd64"
                   publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
                   language="neutral"
                   versionScope="nonSxS"
                   xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <DiskConfiguration>
                <Disk wcm:action="add">
                    <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                    <WillWipeDisk>true</WillWipeDisk>
                    <CreatePartitions>
                        <!-- Windows RE Tools partition -->
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>1</Order>
                            <Type>Primary</Type>
                            <Size>300</Size>
                        </CreatePartition>
                        <!-- System partition (ESP) -->
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>2</Order>
                            <Type>EFI</Type>
                            <Size>100</Size>
                        </CreatePartition>
                        <!-- Microsoft reserved partition (MSR) -->
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>3</Order>
                            <Type>MSR</Type>
                            <Size>128</Size>
                        </CreatePartition>
                        <!-- Windows partition -->
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>4</Order>
                            <Type>Primary</Type>
                            <Extend>true</Extend>
                        </CreatePartition>
                    </CreatePartitions>
                    <ModifyPartitions>
                        <!-- Windows RE Tools partition -->
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>1</Order>
                            <PartitionID>1</PartitionID>
                            <Label>WINRE</Label>
                            <Format>NTFS</Format>
                            <TypeID>DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC</TypeID>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                        <!-- System partition (ESP) -->
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>2</Order>
                            <PartitionID>2</PartitionID>
                            <Label>System</Label>
                            <Format>FAT32</Format>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                        <!-- MSR partition does not need to be modified -->
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>3</Order>
                            <PartitionID>3</PartitionID>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                        <!-- Windows partition -->
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>4</Order>
                            <PartitionID>4</PartitionID>
                            <Label>OS</Label>
                            <Letter>C</Letter>
                            <Format>NTFS</Format>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                    </ModifyPartitions>
                </Disk>
            </DiskConfiguration>
            <ImageInstall>
                <OSImage>
                    <InstallTo>
                        <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                        <PartitionID>4</PartitionID>
                    </InstallTo>
                    <InstallToAvailablePartition>false</InstallToAvailablePartition>
                </OSImage>
            </ImageInstall>
            <UserData>
                <ProductKey>
                    <Key>W269N-WFGWX-YVC9B-4J6C9-T83GX</Key>
                    <WillShowUI>Never</WillShowUI>
                </ProductKey>
                <AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>
                <FullName>Admin</FullName>
                <Organization></Organization>
            </UserData>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="offlineServicing">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-LUA-Settings"
                   processorArchitecture="amd64"
                   publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
                   language="neutral"
                   versionScope="nonSxS"
                   xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <EnableLUA>false</EnableLUA>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core"
                   processorArchitecture="amd64"
                   publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
                   language="neutral"
                   versionScope="nonSxS"
                   xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <InputLocale>0409:00000409</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>en-US</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            <UILanguageFallback>en-US</UILanguageFallback>
            <UserLocale>en-US</UserLocale>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP-UX" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SkipAutoActivation>true</SkipAutoActivation>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-SQMApi"
                   processorArchitecture="amd64"
                   publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
                   language="neutral"
                   versionScope="nonSxS"
                   xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <CEIPEnabled>0</CEIPEnabled>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup"
                   processorArchitecture="amd64"
                   publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
                   language="neutral"
                   versionScope="nonSxS"
                   xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ComputerName>UNNAMED</ComputerName>
            <ProductKey>W269N-WFGWX-YVC9B-4J6C9-T83GX</ProductKey>
        </component>
        <component xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   name="Microsoft-Windows-Deployment"
                   processorArchitecture="amd64"
                   publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
                   language="neutral"
                   versionScope="nonSxS">
            <RunSynchronous>
                <RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>1</Order> 
                    <Path>cmd /q /c "FOR %i IN (C D E F G H I A B J K L N M O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) DO IF EXIST %i:\Win10Deployment\Customize.bat cmd /k %i:\Win10Deployment\Customize.bat"</Path>
                    <Description>Run Custom scripts</Description> 
                </RunSynchronousCommand>
            </RunSynchronous>
        </component>
        <component xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   name="Microsoft-Windows-IE-InternetExplorer"
                   processorArchitecture="amd64"
                   publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
                   language="neutral"
                   versionScope="nonSxS">
            <DisableFirstRunWizard>true</DisableFirstRunWizard>
            <FavoritesDelete>true</FavoritesDelete>
            <Home_Page>http://www.google.com</Home_Page>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup"
                   processorArchitecture="amd64"
                   publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
                   language="neutral"
                   versionScope="nonSxS"
                   xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <AutoLogon>
                <Password>
                    <Value></Value>
                    <PlainText>true</PlainText>
                </Password>
                <Enabled>true</Enabled>
                <Username>Admin</Username>
            </AutoLogon>
            <OOBE>
                <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
                <HideOEMRegistrationScreen>true</HideOEMRegistrationScreen>
                <HideOnlineAccountScreens>true</HideOnlineAccountScreens>
                <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
                <SkipUserOOBE>true</SkipUserOOBE>
                <SkipMachineOOBE>true</SkipMachineOOBE>
                <ProtectYourPC>1</ProtectYourPC>
            </OOBE>
            <UserAccounts>
                <LocalAccounts>
                    <LocalAccount wcm:action="add">
                        <Password>
                            <Value></Value>
                            <PlainText>true</PlainText>
                        </Password>
                        <Description/>
                        <DisplayName>Admin</DisplayName>
                        <Group>Administrators</Group>
                        <Name>Admin</Name>
                    </LocalAccount>
                </LocalAccounts>
            </UserAccounts>
            <DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet>false</DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet>
            <FirstLogonCommands>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>3</Order>
                    <RequiresUserInput>false</RequiresUserInput>
                    <CommandLine>cmd /C wmic useraccount where name="Admin" set PasswordExpires=false</CommandLine>
                    <Description>Password Never Expires</Description>
                </SynchronousCommand>
            </FirstLogonCommands>
            <TimeZone>Pacific Standard Time</TimeZone>
        </component>
    </settings>
</unattend>
```

As anyone else encountered this or know of a way to use an answer file and then use Azure AD accounts?

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific document mentioning the way to use an answer file and then Azure AD account. This scenario requires a deep dive technical troubleshooting need to be done in order to understand and fix. I would suggest you create a Support ticket in order to fix and find the root cause.